# How can I convert this specific timestamp number to a date?

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I have this timestamp and I want to convert it to a date:

```
time     
       Size:       24x1
       Dimensions: time
       Datatype:   int32
       Attributes:
                   units     = 'hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0'
                   long_name = 'time'
                   calendar  = 'gregorian'
```

I've tried with datevec() and datestr(), but they are not giving the correct date. The dates I'm working with are hourly data from 1st October 2018.

```
Time = [1040928;1040929;1040930;1040931;1040932;1040933;1040934;1040935;1040936;1040937;1040938;1040939;1040940;1040941;1040942;1040943;1040944;1040945;1040946;1040947;1040948;1040949;1040950;1040951]
```

**EDIT**
I've got a solution, but when I try to implement it to the whole array I obtain an error.

```
    Error using datevecmx
    The datevecmx function only accepts double arrays.
```

My solution is the following:

```
time = [1034376;1034377;1034378;1034379;1034380;1034381;1034382;1034383;1034384;1034385;1034386;1034387;1034388;1034389;1034390;1034391;1034392;1034393;1034394;1034395;1034396;1034397;1034398;1034399]

ref = datestr(time/24+693962)
x=time/24+693962
time_converted = arrayfun(@(x) datestr(x), x)
```

I convert the date using the reference of year 1900 and then I try to apply the function to the whole array, but I obtain an error.

**EDIT 2** @Finn 's solution

Finn's solution is not working for me.

```
time_transformed = datetime((time/24)+datenum(1900,1,1),'ConvertFrom','datenum')
```

It's giving the following result:

```
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
```

Instead of:

```
   01-Jan-2018 00:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 01:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 02:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 03:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 04:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 05:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 06:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 07:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 08:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 09:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 10:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 11:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 12:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 13:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 14:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 15:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 16:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 17:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 18:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 19:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 20:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 21:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 22:00:00
   01-Jan-2018 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, it's `datetime(X,'ConvertFrom','datenum')`. `X` has to be *Number of days since 0-Jan-0000 (proleptic ISO calendar)* so we have to do a little transformation.

**UPDATE**

Because of the datatype int32 of `time` the hours get lost. It needs to be transformed to a floating point so hours are represented as well.

```
time_transformed = datetime((double(Time)/24)+datenum(1900,1,1),'ConvertFrom','datenum')
```

Comment: I realized that the number of time is the time in hours since 1900-01-01, I don't know if your solution is working for this.

Comment: It is! The  `Time` vector is devided by 24 (so we get days instead of hours) and then the datenum for 1900-01-01 is added to shift it to the right time

Comment: I'm not obtaining the expected result. For 

Time =[1034382;1034383;1034384;1034385;1034386;1034387;1034388;1034389;1034390;1034391;1034392;1034393;1034394;1034395;1034396;1034397;1034398;1034399]


I should obtain dates from 01-01-2018  in hours.

Comment: @Ipa When I use the transformation provided by Finn on your `Time` array I get datetimes from 01-Jan-2018 06:00:00 to 01-Jan-2018 23:00:00. What do you get?

Comment: @Axel see the update! I've achieved a solution, but I have problems implementing it.

Comment: @Ipa This is a limitation from `datestr` as it expects a `DateVector` when an array is used as input. Why does Finn's solution not work for you?

Comment: @Axel see the update **EDIT 2**, that's what I obtain with Finn 's solution.

Comment: @Ipa This is strange. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197480/discussion-between-ipa-and-axel).